# Getting text from input to replace label text in another form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

reposting for simplicity. i want to have the text users enter into an input to replace the label text of another form's input. Additionally, the form is a plugin which doesn't let me attach an id to the specific label tag of the text i want to change. how can i do this, in vanilla javascript please.

the input users put text into:

```
<input class="charInput" id="name1" type="text" onKeyUp="change1(this)" >
```

the form label i want to change the text in (p.s: cant use the class(not unique to this label), cant add id):

```
<div id="frm_field_53_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_top_container">
<label class="frm_primary_label" for="field_inputactor1">
TEXT TO REPLACE
<span class="frm_required"></span>
</label></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is `change1(this)`?

Comment: no, i dont know how to reach the text without having an id in the label...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution, but it is a solution that works in Firefox and Chrome (not tested under IE)

```
findLabelToChange = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("frm_field_53_container");
    return div.querySelector("label");
};

customizeText = function(text) { 
    return text + ' <span class="frm_required"></span>';
};

change1 = function() {
    var label = findLabelToChange();
    var text = document.getElementById("name1").value;

    label.innerHTML = customizeText(text);
};
```

you can see a example in this feedle
http://jsfiddle.net/HAK5X/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle.

It is one line of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/te3jv/6/

```
function change1(myInput){
```

document.getElementById('frm_field_53_container').querySelector("label").innerHTML =myInput.value;

}

Alternatively add `<span class="frm_required"></span>` to the end of HTML reassignment to keep your empty (but required?) span.

Comment: The poster asked for vanilla Javascript, you are using jQuery.

Comment: yes,..and the poster also updated his posting include that requirement once I had started working.

But hey, thanks for the armchair quarterbacking ;-)